# Are there any chips which manages supercap charging and releasing power?

Tags: integrated-circuit, supercapacitor

I'm not looking for recommendations but simply the existence of such a chip, I know where to look for them but want to make sure they do not just exist in my imagination.

I want to use a supercap as not just back up power, but a main source. I want to use a 5V, 12f one, and the cost at this point is of no concern.

There are a plethora of problems associated with supercaps, with voltage dropping being one. And I want a smooth, constant 3.3v output from the super cap.

So I'm thinking, there has to be a chip somewhere which not just monitors the power left, how long it takes to charge it fully, **but also manages its output**? I.e make sure the output stays @ 3.3V for a very long time before going under?

I could be wrong. I need confirmation?

Comment: You are looking for a single chip to do charging, output regulation and monitoring? The answer might depend on where the energy to charge is coming from.

Comment: Yes, precisely that. The power comes from a 5V DC DC module.

Comment: http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3108

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ICs out there which do what you want.

They are usually labelled as backup controller or something like that. Some charging controllers will do what you want as well.

What could be missing is the monitoring aspect. I haven't seen many which give feedback about the state of charge of the backup. There are quite a few monitoring ICs out there, so you might need a combination of two.